# Confusing Dynamic Link Document

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, react-native-ios

I tried to set up dynamic link to my iOS project and follow https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.1.x/links/ios document.

In document number 5. that need to update the `AppDelegate.m` file.
`FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = CUSTOM_URL_SCHEME;`
What is `CUSTOM_URL_SCHEME` ?

From the explanation : ^-- where `CUSTOM_URL_SCHEME` is the custom URL scheme you defined in your Xcode project.

I still really don't know where `CUSTOM_URL_SCHEME` is.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For someone who maybe like me non native developer from react-native.

Can refer to this link https://codorial.com/g/invertase/tutorials/ios-xcode-custom-url-scheme

And what I do is `[FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"com.example.ios";`

Comment: could you please tell me if my firebase dynamic link scheme in the console is example.page.link and my bundle identifier is com.myWebsite.example
So what will be @"com.example.ios" for my case?